# Intellij Tools Layout: Can the project tree take the whole height when debugging?

Tags: eclipse, layout, intellij-idea

I am experimenting with switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. So far, so good. However, Eclipse enables me to configure my workspace whatever way I want, and I am having a lot of trouble configuring even the most basic things in IntelliJ.

In a specific case, I want the debugging view to be on top, and I want the project explorer tree on the left taking the whole height. This is what I want, which I can easily do in Eclipse:

[image: The layout I want, easily done in Eclipse just by dragging the tools.]

In Jetbrain's IntelliJ IDEA I can only achieve this:

[image: What I could achieve in IntelligJ]

Which is obviously awful. I don't need the event log to take the whole width, and I don't need the debugger to take the whole width either. I want the project explorer on the left taking the whole space, and then whatever is left be used by tools on the top and on the bottom.

I confess I'm a bit confused with all the "modes".. split, docked, whatever. I cannot drag things to where I need them, it seems.

Is this even possible? If so, how can I configure that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

It's under `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance`

Select the "Widescreen tool window layout" option.

It could definitely just be drag and drop like Eclipse, though. This is really hidden.